Android端末のカメラでズーム・広角の設定を操作したい
Android Studioで開発しております。
カメラで撮影した画面上に全身を収めたいのですが、端末との距離を大きく離したくないため、ズームの設定を行いました。
カメラ位置は固定で、1～2メートルの距離で全身が映ることを目指しております。
カメラはフロントカメラを使用しております。
Android 12を使用しております。
int mCurrentZoomLevel = 1;
Rect activeArraySize = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
int cx = activeArraySize.centerX();
int cy = activeArraySize.centerY();
int hw = (activeArraySize.width() >> 1) / mCurrentZoomLevel;
int hh = (activeArraySize.height() >> 1) / mCurrentZoomLevel;
Rect mCropRegion = new Rect(cx - hw, cy - hh, cx + hw, cy + hh);
try {
              CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
              captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
              captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, mCropRegion);
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
}

上記のようにズーム設定の行い、引きの映像として対応したいのですが、現状では上半身のみで下半身が映りません。
これ以上のズームでの引きの対応、もしくは広角の設定などの変更などございますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。
